# Autocomplete term suggestion as per popularity

Tags: solr, autocomplete, solr4, solrnet

I have implemented autocomplete term suggestion in my MVC application. Let me explain you how I have done this. I have created one table in DB and table columns is like:

```
Id  SearchTerm  CatID ResultCount Clicks Latency TermSearchTime
```

Now, whenever user search a term we store it in this table. Next time it same word match we display term suggestion. Moreover, we display term suggestion as term popularity. Which word is more searched is displayed first in suggestion.

But now I also want to provide term suggestion for misspell term. For example **Samsung** is already there in my table. If someone search for **samsng** in that case Samsung should be there in term suggestion.

As I do not know how to spell check in SQL server, I decided to do it using Solr.

How can I do it using Solr with my default behaviour which I have done with SQL Db? Moreover, please note Search result I fetch from the Solr. I have already index all products. Do I need to index Search Term as well?

Any help is appreciation. Thanks.

Comment: spellcheck handler will be there in solr. check your solrconfig.xml file. query using /spell handler like /spell?q=ipad  you get ipod word as suggestion since there is no term indexed with word ipad

Comment: Yes, I know there is spell checker. But my problem is I store serach term in DB and provide suggestion as per popularity.

Comment: if results are zero for searchterm then you may consider adding two more columns with names correctlyspelled (values:true, false) termsuggestion(value:possible correct spelling of mis spelled term)

Comment: But what if I want to do it using Solr? Can't we store this data in Solr and use Solr spell check behaviour.

Comment: yes you can. you just use spellcheck handler /spell in solr . if ther searchterm is correct you get documents. if its wrong, you get term suggestion array

Comment: But as I have already one schema defined for products fields. Can I index these fields as well? How can I do it? because I need to store all column data for analytics.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110837/discussion-between-vinod-and-ankita).

Answer (score 0):

check this in your solrconfig.xml file to use spellcheck handler.

```
 <requestHandler name="/spell" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
<lst name="defaults">
  <str name="df">text</str>
  <!-- Solr will use suggestions from both the 'default' spellchecker
       and from the 'wordbreak' spellchecker and combine them.
       collations (re-written queries) can include a combination of
       corrections from both spellcheckers -->
  <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">wordbreak</str>
  <str name="spellcheck">on</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">true</str>       
  <str name="spellcheck.count">10</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.alternativeTermCount">5</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest">5</str>       
  <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.collateExtendedResults">true</str>  
  <str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">10</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.maxCollations">5</str>         
</lst>
<arr name="last-components">
  <str>spellcheck</str>
</arr></requestHandler>
```

if not present then copy paste in your file. restart solr. try `/spell?q=ipad`